# Distinguish key events when HTML document is blocked by a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, modal-dialog

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', event => console.log(event.key))
```

```html
<dialog id="dialog">
  <button onclick="dialog.close()" onfocus="this.blur()">Close</button>
</dialog>
<button onclick="dialog.showModal()">Open</button>
```

For testing purposes the `Close` button is always blurred on focus (so when opening the dialog it has no focus).

How can I trap keydown events so they don't escape the dialog?
If I can't, how can I detect [if the document is blocked by modal dialog](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#dom-dialog-showmodal) (point 7 of the spec) or effectively [inert](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#blocked-by-a-modal-dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

After more digging I have come up with a clever idea.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert states:

> A node (in particular elements and text nodes) can be inert. When a
> node is inert:
>
> - Hit-testing must act as if the 'pointer-events' CSS property were set    to 'none'.
> - Text selection functionality must act as if the 'user-select' CSS    property were set to 'none'.
> - If it is editable, the node behaves as if it were non-editable.
> - The user agent should ignore the node for the purposes of    find-in-page.
>
> > **Inert nodes generally cannot be focused**, and user agents do not expose
> > the inert nodes to accessibility APIs or assistive technologies. Inert
> > nodes that are commands will become inoperable to users, in the manner
> > described above.
>
> User agents may allow the user to override the restrictions on
> find-in-page and text selection, however.
>
> By default, a node is not inert.

So we can simply try to focus a button that is outside of the dialog and check if it actually got focused. Afterwards, restore the focus back to the original element.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  const inertTest = document.getElementById('inert-test');

  const currentFocus = document.activeElement;

  inertTest.focus({
    preventScroll: true,
  });
  const inert = document.activeElement !== inertTest;
  currentFocus.focus({
    preventScroll: true,
  });

  console.log(event.key, inert);
});
```

```html
<!-- This button below *must be* visible -->
<button id="inert-test" style="padding: 0px; border-width: 0px;" tabindex="-1"></button>

<dialog id="dialog">
  <button onclick="dialog.close()" onfocus="this.blur()">Close</button>
  <input />
</dialog>
<button onclick="dialog.showModal()">Open</button>
<input />
```

Comment: I don't like this approach and would prefer more "official" solution. This looks very hacky, but works for now.